# Bootstrap 4 table with the scrollable body and header fixed

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

[image][image]
I am new to front-end-development. Here I have the following table:

```
  <div className="table-responsive">
    <table className="table table-hover" id="job-table">
      <thead>
        <tr className="text-center">
          <th scope="col">Sr.No.</th>
          <th scope="col">Company Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Technology</th>
          <th scope="col">Total Resumes</th>
          <th scope="col">Job Title</th>
          <th scope="col">Total Score</th>
          <th scope="col">Average Score</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody className="text-center">
        {this.props.list && this.props.list.content && this.props.list.content.length > 0 && this.props.list.content.map((item, key) => {
          return (
            <tr key={key}>
              <td className="font-weight-bold">1</td>
              <td className="font-weight-bold">ABCDED</td>
              <td>Software Developer</td>
              <td className="font-weight-bold">17</td>
              <td>5 years experience</td>
              <td className="font-weight-bold">30</td>
              <td className="font-weight-bold">30</td>
            </tr>
          )
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

In this I have used the `table-responsive class`. I have tried to make this table scrollable by using this:

```
tbody { height: 400px; overflow-y: scroll }
```

But this is not working.

One other thing about the content of the `td`, if it is large the other rows gets affected. How can I avoid this scenario?

[image]
[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Comment: This codepen comes closer to solving the issue than the answers posted here: https://codepen.io/bobmarksie/pen/VadxoK

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try using flex, it should be compatible with `table-responsive`:

```
table {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    width: 100%;
}

thead {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}

tbody {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    display: block;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

tr {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Hey this has worked but the thing is that one of my table data has a big content you can say its like more than 100 char so because of that the height of that particular row becomes big . so How can I have this

Comment: @ganesh hi, so what's the problem with my solution?

Comment: No there is  no problem with your solution. its great only thing is that, If one of the row has a td which is having a big content then the height of thatparticuar row becomes very big. I mean it's like word wrap

Comment: @ganesh so what do you expect, just give me more detail for more help.

Comment: No, Actually I am new so, I don't know which is the right way .So, You can guide me a bit for this. Because the first solution which I got also works with that the width issue comes like the width of others gets change

Comment: @ganesh can you give me a screenshot about your rendered table?

Comment: I have just updated the question which has the screen shot . So what I m am saying is that the colum which has the data like aaaaa this data gets varies . it depends upon the text so if it is too large then it will take the two or more lines and the height becomes big and if other same row has the data length less then it gets changes

Comment: Please see the images that I have added

Comment: @ganesh in your case, I think your just shrink width of short content column such as total score, id, avg score. You can also reduce padding of each column.

Comment: could you please help a bit because I think we should not fix the width as it will not work properly on then on tablet screen

Comment: @ganesh just set some column to fixed width and leave the long content column then test in your browser. Flex child will grow the rest width of the row, so it won't be broken in small screen.

Comment: Hey actually, I have one more question which is I have one more footer which has a table. I have added an image, which is exact below this table. So, I have added one more table. Now, it has three rows, now hOw can I get this three rows exact in the same column of last three rows ?

Comment: @ganesh take a look at css selector: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp, if you want to select specific row, for example 3rd row, just use `tr:nth-child(3)` and the same with `td`

Comment: Sorry actually what I want to do is that if you see the image which has some color that this is the footer that I want to have immdiately after this table. So, this footer I have taken as a table. Now the content of this footer should be in the same column I mean like using empty tr 4 times and then it will be in the same column as of 5th column

Comment: @ganesh you might want to mention `colspan`, i.e: `<td colspan="4"></td>`
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp

Comment: If you solve your problems, pls vote up and mark my answer as resolved.

Comment: Yes sure . only thing is that if I set the fixed width then the alignment gets disturbed for other columns

Comment: with this solution I am not able to add the elipses for a table data. I tried but no luck

Comment: Can you please help me with this one line elipses

Comment: Hi @ganesh, please post an image describe what you're trying to approach, I don't understand what you said.

Comment: Hey I have added that image. In that there is this data called urgent opening for  so this data is big. it is dividing it in diff lines. so, what I was trying to do is add elipsses if the data is big . SO that it will stay in one line only.

Comment: That is text-overflow: ellipses but this was not working

Comment: @ganesh try this: `white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;`

Comment: Thanks for your solution.

Comment: When I use this solution the thead cell alignment relative to the tbody cell progressively shifts farther right with each cell.  For instance the first column header and body align correctly but the last column the header is shifted to the right relative to the data in the body underneath.  This shift gets progressively worse with more columns.   Do you know how to correct for this?

Answer (score 53):

Can set fixed header by using `position: sticky`.

Check the [sample code](https://codepen.io/balajidesigner/pen/YBKQBK?editors=1100).

Here set the height to the main container.

```
.table-responsive{height:400px;overflow:scroll;}
```

Set the postion sticky to the tr-> th.

```
thead tr:nth-child(1) th{background: white; position: sticky;top: 0;z-index: 10;}
```

Comment: The linked sample solution works if your fine with everything in each column being centered. which the solution you show here above does not mention and will completely break without the addition of the text-centered class to the thead tr element.

Comment: @Drew I can't understand why it should break without the text-centered class. I just tested and it worked perfectly
@Balaji731 This solution is probably the best one here, as it does not change the width of the columns. The only drawback is that the borders of the `th` are not preserved, and scroll up with the body (we can see that in the sample code link)

Comment: you are the best!

Comment: works for bootstrap 5 too (or any simple html table)

Comment: @Matoran Yes it will work, its common css, so it will work.

Comment: Be careful with the nth child, in case of more than one rows in thead.

Answer (score 7):

add `display:block` to the table to fix this

```
tbody{height: 400px; overflow-y: scroll;display:block;}
th { position: sticky; top: 0; }
```

Comment: this is great , only thing is that , If one of the row has a td which is having a big content then the width of the other rows varies

Comment: This only works if a width is specified on every th and corresponding td.  eg something like this (repeat for each column and change the col target #) : `th:nth-child(1),td:nth-child(1) {width: 50px;}`.  Which is not a good solution

Comment: worked perfectly on bootstrap 4, with a table inside a modal box, viewed with chrome.

Comment: `position: sticky; top: 0; ` works

Answer (score 5):

use position : sticky at 
and top : 0

```
th {
  background: white;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0; /* Don't forget this, required for the stickiness */
}
```

full example can be found here:
https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-and-table-headers/