# Bootstrap 4: Is there a fix/workaround for false anti-aliasing in MS Edge for the border of sticky th

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, microsoft-edge

I will be referencing [this Pen](https://codepen.io/balajidesigner/pen/YBKQBK?editors=1100) from Balaji731's answer in [Bootstrap 4 table with the scrollable body and header fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54286705/bootstrap-4-table-with-the-scrollable-body-and-header-fixed).

So, if you open the Pen in Microsoft Edge, and you have `<th>` borders turned on, they will just scroll away, leave a gap and fail to render the thead contents correctly.

As my personal workaround I have set `border: 0;` on the `<th>`'s , which I actually don't want to. Does anyone have a solution for that?

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-hover" id="job-table">
 <thead>
  <tr class="text-center">
   <th scope="col">Sr.No.</th>
   <th scope="col">Company Name</th>
   <th scope="col">Technology</th>
   <th scope="col">Total Resumes</th>
   <th scope="col">Job Title</th>
   <th scope="col">Total Score</th>
   <th scope="col">Average Score</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr key={key}>
   <td class="font-weight-bold">1</td>
   <td class="font-weight-bold">ABCDED</td>
   <td>Software Developer</td>
   <td class="font-weight-bold">17</td>
   <td>5 years experience</td>
   <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
   <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
  </tr>
   <tr key={key}>
    <td class="font-weight-bold">1</td>
    <td class="font-weight-bold">ABCDED</td>
    <td>Software Developer</td>
    <td class="font-weight-bold">17</td>
    <td>5 years experience</td>
    <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
    <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And the CSS:

```
.table-responsive{
  height:400px;  
  overflow:scroll;
}
thead tr:nth-child(1) th{
  background: white;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

[MS Edge Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhsD3.png)

Comment: Please include all relevant code in the question itself, not just on an external site. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon in editor toolbar looks like `<>`) to provide a runnable example here.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. You're right. I edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the bottom line of the Table heading? which looks thin in the MS Edge browser.

Snapshot from Chrome browser:

[image]

If you want a similar kind of output in MS Edge then you can try to add style below to your TH tag.

```
border-bottom: 4px solid lightgray;
```

Modified code example:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style>
.table-responsive{
  height:400px;  
  overflow:scroll;
}
 thead tr:nth-child(1) th{
    background: white;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    border-bottom: 4px solid lightgray;
        
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-hover" id="job-table">
      <thead>
        <tr class="text-center">
          <th scope="col">Sr.No.</th>
          <th scope="col">Company Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Technology</th>
          <th scope="col">Total Resumes</th>
          <th scope="col">Job Title</th>
          <th scope="col">Total Score</th>
          <th scope="col">Average Score</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="text-center tableBody">
            <tr key={key}>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">1</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">ABCDED</td>
              <td>Software Developer</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">17</td>
              <td>5 years experience</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
            </tr>
        <tr key={key}>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">1</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">ABCDED</td>
              <td>Software Developer</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">17</td>
              <td>5 years experience</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
            </tr><tr key={key}>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">1</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">ABCDED</td>
              <td>Software Developer</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">17</td>
              <td>5 years experience</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
            </tr><tr key={key}>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">1</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">ABCDED</td>
              <td>Software Developer</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">17</td>
              <td>5 years experience</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
            </tr><tr key={key}>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">1</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">ABCDED</td>
              <td>Software Developer</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">17</td>
              <td>5 years experience</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
            </tr><tr key={key}>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">1</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">ABCDED</td>
              <td>Software Developer</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">17</td>
              <td>5 years experience</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
            </tr><tr key={key}>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">1</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">ABCDED</td>
              <td>Software Developer</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">17</td>
              <td>5 years experience</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
            </tr><tr key={key}>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">1</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">ABCDED</td>
              <td>Software Developer</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">17</td>
              <td>5 years experience</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
            </tr>
        <tr key={key}>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">1</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">ABCDED</td>
              <td>Software Developer</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">17</td>
              <td>5 years experience</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
            </tr>
        <tr key={key}>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">1</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">ABCDED</td>
              <td>Software Developer</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">17</td>
              <td>5 years experience</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
            </tr><tr key={key}>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">1</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">ABCDED</td>
              <td>Software Developer</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">17</td>
              <td>5 years experience</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
            </tr><tr key={key}>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">1</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">ABCDED</td>
              <td>Software Developer</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">17</td>
              <td>5 years experience</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
            </tr><tr key={key}>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">1</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">ABCDED</td>
              <td>Software Developer</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">17</td>
              <td>5 years experience</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
            </tr><tr key={key}>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">1</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">ABCDED</td>
              <td>Software Developer</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">17</td>
              <td>5 years experience</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
            </tr><tr key={key}>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">1</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">ABCDED</td>
              <td>Software Developer</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">17</td>
              <td>5 years experience</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
            </tr><tr key={key}>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">1</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">ABCDED</td>
              <td>Software Developer</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">17</td>
              <td>5 years experience</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
            </tr>
        <tr key={key}>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">1</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">ABCDED</td>
              <td>Software Developer</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">17</td>
              <td>5 years experience</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
            </tr>
        <tr key={key}>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">1</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">ABCDED</td>
              <td>Software Developer</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">17</td>
              <td>5 years experience</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
            </tr><tr key={key}>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">1</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">ABCDED</td>
              <td>Software Developer</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">17</td>
              <td>5 years experience</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
            </tr><tr key={key}>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">1</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">ABCDED</td>
              <td>Software Developer</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">17</td>
              <td>5 years experience</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
            </tr><tr key={key}>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">1</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">ABCDED</td>
              <td>Software Developer</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">17</td>
              <td>5 years experience</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
            </tr><tr key={key}>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">1</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">ABCDED</td>
              <td>Software Developer</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">17</td>
              <td>5 years experience</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
            </tr><tr key={key}>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">1</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">ABCDED</td>
              <td>Software Developer</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">17</td>
              <td>5 years experience</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
            </tr><tr key={key}>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">1</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">ABCDED</td>
              <td>Software Developer</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">17</td>
              <td>5 years experience</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
            </tr>
        <tr key={key}>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">1</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">ABCDED</td>
              <td>Software Developer</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">17</td>
              <td>5 years experience</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
            </tr>
        <tr key={key}>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">1</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">ABCDED</td>
              <td>Software Developer</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">17</td>
              <td>5 years experience</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
            </tr><tr key={key}>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">1</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">ABCDED</td>
              <td>Software Developer</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">17</td>
              <td>5 years experience</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
            </tr><tr key={key}>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">1</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">ABCDED</td>
              <td>Software Developer</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">17</td>
              <td>5 years experience</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
            </tr><tr key={key}>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">1</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">ABCDED</td>
              <td>Software Developer</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">17</td>
              <td>5 years experience</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
            </tr><tr key={key}>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">1</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">ABCDED</td>
              <td>Software Developer</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">17</td>
              <td>5 years experience</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
            </tr><tr key={key}>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">1</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">ABCDED</td>
              <td>Software Developer</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">17</td>
              <td>5 years experience</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
            </tr><tr key={key}>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">1</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">ABCDED</td>
              <td>Software Developer</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">17</td>
              <td>5 years experience</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
              <td class="font-weight-bold">30</td>
            </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Output in MS Edge browser:

[image]

Let me know if I misunderstood anything. I will try to correct myself.

Comment: The problem is about the rendering of text in a fixed th. If I run your code snippet in MS Edge the contents of the `<th>`'s aren't rendered correctly. Just compare "Sr.No." or any other `<th>` with the text of the `<td>`'s beneath them. Hope this better presents the problem? :)

Comment: I tried to check the text in TH in MS Edge and Chrome browser. Based on my testing result, both browsers showing similar results. I did not see any other issues there. Can you please try to post the snapshot of the issue? It can help us to understand the issue properly. Also, let us know which version of MS Edge you are using for making this test?

Comment: I updatet the original post and added a link with the screenshot since I am not yet allowed to post images. As for the MS Edge version: Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0 and Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.18363

Comment: I try to check the image and found that the content of the TH are displayed in 2 lines. It is possible that you are resizing the screen and it looks like this because there is no enough space to display it in 1 line. You will get a similar output in every browser, it is not specific with Edge browser. If you want to display it in single line then you need to set min-width:950px; for .table-responsive CSS class. Then it will not shrink and content will be displayed in single line.

Comment: Sadley, this doesn't work for me. Also, my monitor displays it at a even larger width, so I don't see a connection there. There is enough space to display it in one line.

Comment: Not sure, but your snapshot shows that table displaying in very small width. If that is not issue then I suggest you to properly describe your issue. We will again try to check it. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Let's see. The problem is, that the words/edges of the text inside the table head aren't clean, when I haven't scrolled/when I scrolled to the top of the table. From what I have found out the problem occurs in every browser, but in the MS Edge you can see it "best".

Comment: I am able to see that issue now. Header text looks blurry but when it gets scrolled it gets fixed by itself. I noticed that it is staying blur for more time in that code pen window but when I try to run the same code locally it gets blur for fraction of second and then it gets a fix by itself. I suggest you provide the feedback to Bootstrap as we cannot fix this issue by code.

Comment: Thanks. I will do that and report in later.