# How to create sticky header in react-bootstrap/table?

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I make some reaserch on stack overflow, some topic have similar question, but they usually was asking about another library.

In most cases `position: sticky; top: -1px` give the sticky header Table. In my case do not get it.

```
           <thead
      style={{position: "sticky", top: 0}}
            >
              <tr>

                <th  style={{position: "sticky", top: "-1px"}} scope="col">y </th>
                <th  style={{position: "sticky", top: "-1px"}} scope="col">x </th>
                <th  style={{position: "sticky", top: "-1px"}} scope="col">z</th>

          
              </tr>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Table fixed header and scrollable body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168521/table-fixed-header-and-scrollable-body)

Comment: You don't need to set the style for each `<th>`, just the `<thead>`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63956237/378779

Comment: Remember, anytime `position: sticky` is being used, none of the parent element can have `overflow: hidden` on them. This will cause it to not work.